# How can I show the opened file in the same tab after clicking to go to a definition in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VS Code, is it possible to open a new tab for a different file after clicking on a definition of a function where I want to see the new file in the same current tab?

For example, there is a tab opened and it shows ABC.js

In this ABC.js, there is a code which is DEF.functionA()

When I click on `functionA()`, VS Code will open another new tab and show function A() of DEF.js in the new second tab.

Rather than showing in the second new tab, I want DEF.js to be shown in the first tab and replace the content of ABC.js. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of this writing, I am not aware of any setting that enables the behaviour you are looking for (having searched through settings with fuzzy search that have "goto", "replace", "definition", or "location" in their name, and skimming the ones with "open" in their name).

I also tried googling for existing feature request tickets with "`github vscode issues "replace" current tab when "go to definition"`" and didn't see anything that looked like an existing feature request in the top search results.

If you want such a feature, you [can create a feature request issue ticket](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=feature_request.md).

Comment: This is what I think too. I have been googling, texting chatgpt, and my friends and they provide similar answer.

Comment: @CharlesBrown if you can't find it with google why do you think ChatGPT will help, ChatGPT only repeat text that was found in the training set

Comment: If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to the issue ticket, or notify me in the issue ticket with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.